# NonNull local variables

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to use `@NonNull` for local variables in Java? I am using Spring with `@NonNullApi` and `@NonNullFields` annotated in `package-info.java` but I don't seem to get the same warnings in my IDE for local variables as I do for fields, methods, and parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the behavior I was looking for, I ended up creating an annotation and dropping `@NonNullFields` and `@NonNullApi`.

Here's the annotation I used:

```
    import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
    import javax.annotation.meta.TypeQualifierDefault;
    import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

    /**
     * This annotation can be applied to a package, class or method to indicate that the class fields,
     * method return types and parameters in that element are not null by default unless there is:
     * The method overrides a method in a superclass (in which
     * case the annotation of the corresponding parameter in the superclass applies) there is a
     * default parameter annotation applied to a more tightly nested element.
     */
    @Documented
    @Nonnull
    @TypeQualifierDefault(
            {
                    ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE,
                    ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
                    ElementType.FIELD,
                    ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE,
                    ElementType.METHOD,
                    ElementType.PACKAGE,
                    ElementType.PARAMETER,
                    ElementType.TYPE
            })
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface NonNullByDefault {

    }
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: Annotate a package with it in `package-info.java` and it will make the IDE treat everything in the `@TypeQualifierDefault` list as non-null. So all variables are non-null by default, and if a variable can contain null you have to annotate it with `@Nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You could make your variable `final`. This will have the effect of it not being allowed to be `null`, but this is a compile time feature, as opposed to validating parameters at Runtime, so they are two different concepts. Kotlin has the Nullable [concept](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html), but in Java there is only really `Optional`, which isn't the same.

If you want to add request parameter validation to functions and or variables at runtime, this is a classic example of Aspect Oriented Programming, and in Java you would need to rely on some sort of special magic such as Spring to do this (or AspectJ etc.), but behind the scenes will be using simple design patterns such as Proxy, or whatever it is there are many ways to skin a cat.

Annotations are just meta-data at the end of the day, and rely on something else reading and interpreting them appropriately, if you use a `Spring` annotation, it probably needs to be used on a method/field in a `Spring` bean.

Comment: I figured out a way, see my answer. All I was looking for was a way to have local variables be NNBD at development time.